# Selectional number formatting of array values

Tags: php, arrays, number-formatting

I have two types of numbers (FLOAT and BIGINT) in a mysql table.

A:0.002

B: 51443234

I need to replace "." with "," in the numbers and I can do it by number_format

```
foreach ($row as $key => $val) { 
                if (is_numeric($val)) {

                        $row[$key] = number_format($val,'3', ',', '.'); }
                }
            }
```

new format is:

A: 0,002

B:51.443.234,000

but I don't want the trailing zeros in number B, so I try to format FLOAT and BIGINT values separately:

```
foreach ($row as $key => $val) { 
                if (is_numeric($val)) {
                        if (is_float($val)) {
                        $row[$key] = number_format($val,'3', ',', '.'); }
                        else {
                        $row[$key] = number_format($val,'0', ',', '.'); }
                }
            }
```

but this doesn't work.

I'm not sure where the problem is and if I can do it without converting values to string.

(I don't know what is the disadvantage of converting to strings either..)

Can you please show the right approach?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a loosely typed language, therefore it doesn't know about *FLOATS* and *BIGINTS*.  In fact, neither `0,002` or `51.443.234` are valid values.

For doing calculations, don't change anything. For displaying your numbers, format them however you want, even if they're strings.

```
1. <?php
2. $float = 2.25;
3. $bigInt = 4235234;
4.
5. $commaFloat = 2,25;
6. $commaBigInt = 4.235.234;
7. ?>

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 5
```

http://codepad.org/epIuX8MZ

Comment: So, do you suggest formatting every variable one by one in the code?

Comment: No, only when displaying the numbers.  Write a functions that formats the numbers however you want, and call the function every time you want to output a number. _i.e._ `<?= myNumberFormat($someValue); ?>`

Comment: I have near 50 number variables and I have to list them. So I will write two different functions (one for floats, one for bigints), then use them when needed. This is a solution, but I still wonder if I can do it in just one function. Thank you.

Comment: Sure you can. You can use function parameters to explicitly define the number type. For example, `function myNumberFormat($number, $format) {}` **OR** Try to automatically figure out the format for this number, perhaps using RegEx. It should be relatively easy function to write. Have fun with it!

Comment: Thanks for the idea.
I wrote a function like this: myNumberFormat($number, $decimal) {}
for bigint numbers $decimal is 0, for float numbers it depends..